# How to build a class path to other jar files in a manifest

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, manifest

I am currently trying to read and write to excel (xlsx not xls) from java using Apache POI.  The problem is I need not only the poi-ooxml jars but also the dependencies.  How can I create a class path to link all these together?

The ones I am currently using include:

- poi-ooxml-3.10
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10
- dom4j- 1.6.1
- xmlbeans-2.3.0
- stax-api-1.0.1

Also do I write them into the poi-ooxml manifest or do I create an entirely new one?  Sorry I am a bit of a rookie.

This is the poi-ooxml-3.10 manifest just for reference if needed

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.7.0_51-b13 (Oracle Corporation)
Built-By: yegor
Specification-Title: Apache POI
Specification-Version: 3.10-FINAL
Specification-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Title: Apache POI
Implementation-Version: 3.10-FINAL
Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.apache.poi
Implementation-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the MANIFEST.MF, you can add one attribute called "Class-Path"

```
Class-Path: MyUtils.jar MyCommon.jar
```

It should separate with space